# Add property and value in a object array

Tags: php, laravel

im quite new in php OOP, and im using laravel has my framework of choice. Im creating a object user and create the record, the only thing i have to do is to check if one of my input fields(not required) was set, if it was set than i have to add in in the user object, but how can i add this property (mobilephone) and value in a exiting object, am i doing it right?.

code:

```
$user = User::create([
    'email'              => $userDat['email'],
    'name'               => $userDat['name'],
    'surname'            => $userDat['surname'],
]);

if (isset($userDat['mobilephone'])) {
    $user->mobilephone = $userDat['mobilephone'];
}
```

Answer (score 3):

If you absolutely have to add the property to the object, I believe you could cast it as an array, add your property (as a new array key), then cast it back as an object. The only time you run into stdClass objects (I believe) is when you cast an array as an object or when you create a new stdClass object from scratch (and of course when you json_decode() something - silly me for forgetting!).

Instead of:

```
$foo = new StdClass();
$foo->bar = '1234';
```

You'd do:

```
$foo = array('bar' => '1234');
$foo = (object)$foo;
```

Or if you already had an existing stdClass object:

```
$foo = (array)$foo;
$foo['bar'] = '1234';
$foo = (object)$foo;
```

Also as a 1 liner:

```
$foo = (object) array_merge( (array)$foo, array( 'bar' => '1234' ) );
```

---

or maybe you could do it this way

```
$user->{'mobilephone'} = $userDat['mobilephone'];
```

Answer (score 3):

There're a few ways you can do it.

Prepare the array in advance

```
$data = [
    'email'              => $userDat['email'],
    'name'               => $userDat['name'],
    'surname'            => $userDat['surname'],
];

if ($phone = array_get($userDat, 'mobilephone')) {
    $data['mobilephone'] = $phone;
}

User::create($data);
```

Or create the object first then save it

```
$user = new User([
    'email'              => $userDat['email'],
    'name'               => $userDat['name'],
    'surname'            => $userDat['surname'],
]);

if ($phone = array_get($userDat, 'mobilephone')) {
    $user->mobilephone = $phone;
}

$user->save();
```

As you are currently, but with an extra query (Ill advised)

```
$user = User::create([
    'email'              => $userDat['email'],
    'name'               => $userDat['name'],
    'surname'            => $userDat['surname'],
]);

if ($phone = array_get($userDat, 'mobilephone')) {
    $user->mobilephone = $phone;

    $user->save();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

> how can i add this property (mobilephone) and value in a exiting object, am i doing it right?.

This strongly depends on which framework you are using. In general, you *can* add arbitrary properties to any object in PHP (which does not mean you always *should*).

In your case, you are using the [Eloquent](https://laravel.com/docs/5.2/eloquent) framework that's shipped with Laravel, which actually *depends* on dynamically assigned object attributes and are **using it absolutely correctly**. This is documented in-depth in the [official documentation](https://laravel.com/docs/5.2/eloquent#inserting-and-updating-models). Note that you'll probably have to call `$user->save()` at some point to actually save your user object (thanks to Ben for the hint).

Note that alternatively, you could assign *all* properties of your `User` instance that way:

```
$user = new User();
$user->email   = $userDat['email'];
$user->name    = $userDat['name'];
$user->surname = $userDat['surname'];

if (isset($userDat['mobilephone'])) {
    $user->mobilephone = $userDat['mobilephone'];
}

$user->save();
```

Comment: Bold absolutely correctly is only true if OP doesn't want to persist the change on the object. Otherwise, you need to call `$user->save()` too.

Comment: I considered persistence as out-of-scope for this, as the OP did not explicitly ask about it.

Comment: Indeed, however given that the data comes from "input fields" and the others are saved, it stands to reason that it'd need to be persisted so it's worth mentioning.

Comment: Sounds reasonable. I've updated my answer to mention the persistence aspect. Thanks for the hint.